# Alternative for preg_replace_callback() in PHP 8.1?

Tags: php, compatibility

I have the following code:

```
$comment_content = preg_replace_callback('/\[([^][]*)]\(([^()]*)\)|(\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/i',
    create_function('$m','
      if(isset($m[3])) {
          return "<span><a href=\"".$m[3]."\" target=\"_blank\">آدرس بدون عنوان</a></span>";
       } else {
          return "<span><a href=\"".$m[2]."\" target=\"_blank\">".$m[1]."</a></span>";
                        }
     '), $comment_content);
```

That was working well on PHP 7.2, but since I've changed my server to Ubuntu 22.04 and it uses PHP 8.1, now that code is broken.

Any idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$comment_content = preg_replace_callback('/\[([^][]*)]\(([^()]*)\)|(\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/i',
    function ($m) {
        if (isset($m[3])) {
            return "<span><a href=\"".$m[3]."\" target=\"_blank\">آدرس بدون عنوان</a></span>";
        } else {
            return "<span><a href=\"".$m[2]."\" target=\"_blank\">".$m[1]."</a></span>";
        }
    },
    $comment_content
);
```

Comment: What did you change? Please add explanations!

Comment: I got rid of create_function as its not supported with that version.